# UIImage to slide downwards using animation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

How can implement image sliding down animation in ios app?

I've used this code:

```
    imageview.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"img10.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"img11.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img12.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img13.png"],nil];
    imageview.animationDuration = 10.00;  

    imageview.animationRepeatCount = 0; 

    [imageview startAnimating];
```

But this is only a simple slide show. 
Help me.

Comment: you add the imageview in view??

Comment: Instead of using imageView's built in animations, consider putting all images inside a scrollView (using an imageView per each image) and scroll upwards/downwards using a timer by invoking scrollRectToVisible.

Comment: what you want..slide complete imageView or just images

Comment: ok...just use one view...and inside this view add your imageView and change x , y of your image view..

Comment: @Rajneesh071: how can i set x,y? plz help me

Comment: i will give you logic.. just display one image in imageView then after few delay remove first image and add second image and at this time change frame of image view..and as so on... just think and apply

Answer (score 0):

try with this code..

```
      imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
      imageview.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"img10.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"img11.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img12.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img13.png"],nil];

        imageview.animationDuration = 1.25;
        imageview.animationRepeatCount = 10;
        [imageview startAnimating];
        [self.view addSubview:animationView];
        [imageview release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code

```
   -(void) createNewImage {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];

        imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"img10.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"img11.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"img12.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"img13.png"],nil];
        [imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
        imageView.animationDuration =1.5;
        [imageView startAnimating]; 
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(setLastImage:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

     }

    -(void)setLastImage:(id)obj
    {
        [imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img12.png"] waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the centre of `UIImageView` using imgVw.centre, you can update the centre with `NSTimer`. Vary the centre according to the screen, you can get screen height from
`[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height`

```
theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f 
        target:self 
        selector:@selector(updateTimer:) 
        userInfo:nil 
        repeats:YES];

- (void)updateTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    //update centre; 
    imgVw.centre.y += 4;
// you can update the image also if needed use if case
imgVw.image = image2;

}
```